# Are there any applications currently offering a Protocol Buffers API?

Tags: protocol-buffers, lifx

I recently stumbled upon Google's Protocol Buffers as a Kickstarter project I'm following, Lifx, plans to release an SDK utilizing Protocol Buffers as the interface. I was just wondering if anyone knows of any existing applications or services offering a Protocol Buffers API? I am just looking to get some experience playing around with it.

Answer (score 2):

Protocol buffers is first and foremost a mechanism to serialize your program data into binary format (for storage or transfer over the network ) and back again - in a programming language independent way. ie. you can serialize a complex data structure to binary in python app and read it back into an android app and get the same data in the android app's programming language. Protocol buffers doesn't help you transfer or send the data from one place to another - for this you need some other mechanism ( TCP/IP , sockets, HTTP ). Protocol buffers does however provide an API for performing RPC calls from a client to a remote server - but doesn't provide any implementation. There are some 3rd party implementations of this particular RPC api which can be used with any java application - see https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-rpc-pro/ - which might work on android.